# External monitor connected to laptop stays black

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, hdmi, dvi

I have a MSI GE62 6QD Apache Pro (that is my laptop full name) and it only has an HDMI port.

I had desktop PC before with a monitor (It is a Acer S220HQL) but the connector is only a DVI-D port. So, I purchased a 'DVI to HDMI' convertor.

Once it's all connected, my laptop recognizes the monitor (I see it in Device Manager) but the monitor stays black.

Any idea how to fix?

Comment: Did you enable the external display output (there's probably a Function key)?

Comment: Yes I did. I tried setting it to Duplicate and Extend, both not working. I also tried changing the resolution of the monitor without success. Also, when I did an 'extent', I could move my mouse to the new screen (I couldn't see it though)

Comment: *"I purchased a 'DVI to HDMI' convertor."* -- What exactly did you get?  Actually you would need an HDMI-to-DVI adapter.

Comment: I have that adapter. My laptop recognizes the monitor, but simply stays black :-(. After searching through the net, it might be because my laptop doesn't accept a DVI-D to HDMI (but would accept DVI-I ...) I'm starting to think the only solution will be to purchase a new monitor.